# How to assign a value to a <span> within a magnificpopup window?

Tags: magnific-popup

I can access current .html() value of a span contained in a magnificPopup.
But I can not set this value.
This is what I mean:

```
            parseAjax: function(mfpResponse) {
                // This works perfectly
                var mycontent = $(mfpResponse.data).find('#textreported').html();
                // But this does not work
                $(mfpResponse.data).find('#textreported').html('Text to be assigned');
            }
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer myself. This is the right way to do it:

```
            parseAjax: function (mfpResponse) {
                str = jQuery.parseHTML(mfpResponse.data)
                $(str).find('#textreported').html('Text to be assigned');
                mfpResponse.data = $(str)
            }
```

It may be useful to someone.